# Vuejs + Laravel: How To Count Records

Tags: laravel, vue.js, count, console.log

Code for vue component:

```
        data() {
            return {
                patrons : {},
              }
            },
            methods: {
              loadPatron(){
                   axios.get("api/patron")
                       .then(({data}) => (this.patrons= data.data));


              //Count records
              console.log(this.patrons.length); //This line of code does not seem to work.
              },
            }
```

How do we count the records and display them in the console.log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place `console.log` either inside axios get function after assignment

```js
axios.get("api/patron")
   .then(({data}) => {
      this.patrons = data.data
      console.log(this.patrons);
   });
```

or create watcher for `patrons` property and `console.log` there

```js
watch: {
   patrons: {
     handler: function() {
       console.log(this.patrons)
     },
     deep: true
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. How do I do this? If you have time can you show the code. Thank you.